# DynamoDB write latency

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am experiencing high latency when updating items in DynamoDB.
I created a table named PerfTest with a hash key and executed the following command is shell on my computer.

```
time aws dynamodb update-item --table-name "PerfTest" --key '{ "id": { "S": "b3fcb08d-79bd-47f3-a52d-d6a4c3543060" }}' --attribute-updates '{ "counter": {"Value": {"N": "1000"}, "Action": "ADD"}}' --return-values NONE
```

Time gave the following
real    0m1.285s
user    0m0.142s
sys 0m0.038s

I executed the same from an m1.micro instance and it still wrote 0.5 seconds.
It's a little bit better via the Java API but I still cannot get close to the 1ms latency that others mention.

What shall I know to fix this?

Thanks, 
rp

Comment: Where are you trying to connect from? EC2 instance? In the same region as the table?

Comment: The results seem to include connection time, spawning a new Python interpreter, and other one-time setup tasks. You may want to measure timings after connection has been established and for multiple requests. That would help provide latencies in steady state which is probably what you are looking for. Also, as Guy points out, running it on an EC2 instance in the same region will reduce other effects like internet latency.   If you decide to make multiple requests per second, also see the developer guide about setting up provisioned throughput on a table to avoid throttling.

Comment: Yes, I tried from the same region but from a micro instance. Does this affect latency?